# how to install NIS client on windows server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, nis

how to install NIS client on windows server 2012?

Can I do it or not?

It seems only migrate it but no client

Comment: NIS ***Client***? I don't believe this is possible...

Comment: Then if I don't use client, how can I make windows-server access the file system of NFS(it can only read but has no right to write)?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same answer, and I found this.  Maybe this would help:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731178.aspx?ppud=4

### To install Identity Management for UNIX components

- Open Server Manager. To open Server Manager, click Start , point to Administrative Tools , and then click Server Manager.
- In the tree pane, expand Roles.
- On the role home page for AD DS, in the Roles section, in the list of common tasks, click Add Role Services.
- On the Select Role Services page of the Add Role Services Wizard, select the Identity Management for UNIX role services that you want to install, and then click Next.
- If the wizard prompts you to install any other role services that are required by Identity Management for UNIX components, click Yes.
- After verifying your selections on the Confirm Installation Selections page, click Install.
- The computer must be restarted after the installation of Identity Management for UNIX finishes.

Comment: I edited my response to include text from the link